# Setting up emacsformacosx as default from command line

Tags: macos, shell, emacs

I tried to set emacsformaxosx as the emacs command called from the command line (in order to install mu4e) by putting the following inside /usr/bin/emacs:

```
#!/bin/bash
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@"
```

When calling `. /usr/bin/emacs` emacs get launched but when calling `which emacs` I get nothing in my prompt, neither do I with just `emacs`. `whereis emacs` seem to find well that emacs is in /usr/bin/emacs.

Comment: What shell do you use? It's generally not recommended to use `which`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then. Show output of `command -v emacs`. Also, what happens when you are in a different directory than `/usr/bin` and just type `emacs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run

```
chmod a+x /usr/bin/emacs
```

to make the `/usr/bin/emacs` script executable.

The reason it works with the command

```
. /usr/bin/emacs
```

is that in that case, your shell sources the contents of the `/usr/bin/emacs` script and directly runs each command it finds there.

Also, note that since the shell script has nothing else to do after running `emacs`, you could add the command `exec` in front of the `emacs` command in the script so that the `emacs` process replaces the shell script process:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@"
```